# Function parameter not getting the value directly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can someone please explain why the function not getting the value of the object in the first way?

I got the Backbone.View:

```
var some.view =  Backbone.View.extend({
elements = {},
//...
//some init, filling up elements...
//...
stopTask: function() {
   // Calling the function with parameters explained later
   stopThisTask(...);
}
});
```

And the function:

```
function stopThisTask(task){
    console.log(task); 
}
```

When I call `stopThisTask` in the following way, the `task` parameter is *undefined*

```
stopThisTask(this.elements);
```

However, when I do it like this, the `task` has the value

```
var tmp = this.elements;
stopThisTask(tmp);
```

Can someone please explain why is that?
If I know right the variables are passed by value, and the obects are passed by references. However, does that mean in some way I loose the reference for the elements object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting that the `this.elements` gets resolved inside the stopThisTask function, so `this` will point to `stopThisTask` instead of to the caller of `stopThisTask`.
By explicitly setting the `tmp` parameter in the caller, you guarantee the correct `this` scope is used.

Should be equivalent to

```
stopThisTask.call(this, this.elements);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess i'll just have to work this thing around.